# two index type pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a news section on my site and I have plugged it into the word-press CMS. I would like the index page to show some thumbnails and an excerpt of the post then when you click on a blog title I want it to go to another page with all the posts on but set up in a different format.

I've tried creating a file called newsFeed.php that the index can link to but I can't seem to link to it properly. I tried using `<?php (TEMPLATEPATH.'newsFeed.php'); ?>` to link to the page but it keeps returning `NULL`.

Am I going the best way about this? It seemed like such a simple Idea at the time but it's turned into a bit of a mini nightmare lol

Comment: Try:   <?php (TEMPLATEPATH.'/newsFeed.php'); ?> to include your file

Answer (score 0):

in your newsFeed.php include the following code at the top of the page

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News
*/
?>
```

Create a new page, call it News. Make a note of the page ID (quickest way to do this, on the list of pages in the page section, hover over the new page and the link will show the page ID in the full URL). Select `'News'` as the page template.

Use

```
<?php wp_list_pages('include=7); ?>
```

where `7` is the page ID of the news page, wherever you want the link to be on your home page.